# BeautifulSoup output is always " b' ' "

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Regardless of what html file I use, my output is repeatedly b' '.

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = "C:/Users/George/Desktop/bsTest"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

Can somebody please help me fix this issue?

Comment: Try adding .html on to the end of bsTest

Comment: Thanks for  the quick response, Splinxyy. Sadly, this did not change the output.

Comment: What makes you think you can pass a file path into the `BeautifulSoup` constructor? I recommend reading the module's documentation before trying to use it.

Comment: Can you provide the output of html_doc?  Print it in your script and produce the output.

Comment: Read the documentation. Programming by guessing doesn't work, as you've discovered.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just pass the file path as you are attempting to. Please refer to the documentation [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup).

`with open("C:/Users/George/Desktop/bsTest") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')`

Comment: Thank you for the advice. When I run the edited code, my output is the following: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/George/Desktop/HTMLs/temp_10_40.html' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

Comment: Seems correct. Now you'll need to follow the documentation for the actual parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the document before you try to parse the variable.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = "C:/Users/George/Desktop/bsTest"
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(html_doc).read(), 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. When I run the edited code, my output is the following: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/George/Desktop/HTMLs/temp_10_40.html' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

Comment: I forgot to add the read() method to the open. I updated the answer. Give it a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: When using the updated code, the output is unchanged.